# Sudden reboot and system freezes in xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, freeze, reboot

I have a system running xubuntu 18.04. I have a problem with the stability of my system. From time to time the computer just reboots. Yesterday straight from desktop while the system was idling. Today while I was writing an email.

My first thought was the psu is broken. On the other hand, the psu is a quality one and big enough.

Additionally, I have sometimes complete system freezes were the image stays available, but the machine does not recognizes any mouse and keyboard inputs anymore.

So my question is, what would be a good strategy on finding the error.

For example where do I look after a sudden reboot or a system freeze? Or what shall Ill observe while using the system?

Thank you for your time
M.

Comment: You should try to narrow it down it devices. Check whether screen freeze is an issue of GPU or your monitor. Restart could be initiated because of some error in a device buffer, like windows BSOD. If you find your hardware to be fine try to check for logs made by your system at "/var/log/syslog"

Comment: `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` in a terminal shows the last log entries of the previous boot. Consider overheat problems, especially if logs show no pattern. Check your fan and dust bunny collection.

Comment: That smells like GPU problems. Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250533/edit) your question and add the output of `lspci -v | grep -i vga` to it?